# OpenDNS not working from 1 Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, opendns

I have [OpenDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) set up on my **router**, however I'm getting a strange situation.  The [OpenDNS Welcome](http://www.opendns.com/welcome/) page confirms that OpenDNS is **working** on my Windows XP laptop **and** on an Ubuntu netbook but **not** on my Ubuntu desktop (it gets the "oops" page)!

Does it have something to do with the fact that the desktop is wired to the router while the laptops are using wireless?  Or is it possible that the Ubuntu desktop is somehow configured to use a certain DNS server (not OpenDNS) instead of getting it from the router... how could I check that?  I rebooted the ubuntu desktop and it's still getting the "oops" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... my Ubuntu desktop was configured to use my ISP's DNS.  To fix it, I went into System-Administration-Network-DNS (must Unlock first), removed the 2 IP addresses there and replaced them with the IP address of my router (192.168.1.1)

Comment: this must be a comment